# Why does the textbook uses an initializer list as the return value of operator-(complex a)?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, operator-overloading, initializer-list

I am reading a textbook (of Bjarne Stroustrup) definition of class `complex`

```
class complex {
    double re, im; // representation: two doubles
public:
    complex(double r, double i) :re{r}, im{i} {} // construct complex from two scalars
    complex(double r) :re{r}, im{0} {}           // construct complex from one scalar
    complex() :re{0}, im{0} {}                   // default complex: {0,0}

    double real() const { return re; }
    void ral(double d) { re = d; }
    double imag() const { return im; }
    void imag(double d) { im = d; }

    complex& operator+=(complex z) { re+=z.re, im+=z.im; return *this; } // add to re and im
                                                                         // and return the result
    complex& operator-=(complex z) { re-=z.re, im-=z.im; return *this; }


    complex& operator*=(complex); // defined out-of-class somewhere
    complex& operator/=(complex); // defined out-of-class somewhere
};
```

The book also defines operations of complex:

```
complex operator+(complex a, complex b) { return a+=b; }
complex operator-(complex a, complex b) { return a-=b; }
complex operator-(complex a) { return {-a.real(), -a.imag()}; } // unary minus
complex operator*(complex a, complex b) { return a*=b; }
complex operator/(complex a, complex b) { return a/=b; }
```

I do not understand the third line above, which deals with unary minus. Why does it make sense to use an initializer list as the return value of  `operator-(complex a);`?

Comment: Please post code as text, not images.  Not everyone can see pictures.

Comment: That `return` will invoke the constructor `complex(double r, double i)` to make a new object as the return value.

Comment: My question to you is: Why *doesn't* it make sense? You'll get better answers that way :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to have

```
return {-a.real(), -a.imag()};
```

because you want to return a `complex` that is created from those two values.  If you tried using

```
return -a.real(), -a.imag();
```

instead then you would return a `complex` that was created from just `-a.imag()` since the comma operator only returns the last value.  Essentially, the code is exactly the same as

```
return -a.imag();
```

To make it more explicit, the author could have written

```
return complex{-a.real(), -a.imag()};
//or
return complex(-a.real(), -a.imag());
```

but that really isn't needed since the return value is always converted to the return type and with initializer lists, they are used like you had typed `return_type{ initializers }`.

Answer (score 2):

Without the initializer list you have to write

```
complex operator-( complex a ) { return complex( -a.real(), -a.imag() ); }
```

With the initializer list the definition of the operator looks simpler.

In any case the compiler selects the constructor

```
complex( double, double );
```

Take into account that in general the function should be declared like

```
complex operator-( const complex &a ) { return { -a.real(), -a.imag() }; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The return type of that function is a `complex` object, so those parameters in the intitializer list are inferred as parameters to `complex` constructor and a new object is returned.